# Правильная вставка файлов

Tags: файлы, php

Здравствуйте, я применяю такую такую тактику: есть главная страница, например admin.php и через переменную в гет запросе `?show=add_product`  вставляется файл `admin/add_product.php` . Как сделать так чтобы без участия страницы admin.php страницы admin/add_product.php была недоступна. То есть по такому адресу доступно: `admin.php?show=add_product` а по такому нет: `admin/add_product.php`. Как это сделать? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, в htaccess папки `admin` прописать:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files admin.php>
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

По молодости делал так:

В admin.php создавал переменную

```
$ItAdmin = true;
```

В остальных проверку

```
if(isset($ItAdmin) && $ItAdmin!=false) {
      /// Ваш код
}
```